# Tem como chamar apenas uma ou duas classes de uma biblioteca inteira em HTML/Css

Tags: html, css, materialize

Eu estou fazendo um site e já estou finalizando, porém para deixar meu site responsivo eu precisaria de duas classes da biblioteca Materialize.
A intenção era pegar apenas essas duas classes porque ao inserir a biblioteca inteira o meu site todo se altera. (Site sem o link da biblioteca e o site com o link da biblioteca, respectivamente)
[image: Site sem o link da biblioteca ()]

[image: Site com o link da biblioteca]

Comment: Tá, mas qual biblioteca está usando?

Comment: Quando eu aprendi me ensinaram a fazer minhas próprias classes, meu próprio .menu por exemplo, fora isso eu usei bootstrap para as colunas

Comment: Mais a biblioteca é sua então?

Comment: A biblioteca que eu quero importar é a Materialize, tipo colocar o link e depois especificar que eu quero apenar a classe x e y
Por exemplo:
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" >
e ai definir de alguma maneira que as unicas coisas que eu quero pegar de lá são as classes sidenav-trigger e sidenav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não é possível importar só uma classe de um arquivo ou biblioteca css.** O que você poderia fazer é marcar as classes que irão sobrescrever tudo com o elemento `!important` tag no CSS, o que significa que ela não será sobrescrita, e usar só a classe que você quer da biblioteca. **Outra** coisa que você pode fazer é ir nesta biblioteca online, pegar somente as classes que você irá utilizar e colocar em um arquivo e usar :)